# Find a better control

Tags: silverlight, algorithm, user-controls, controls, silverlight-4.0

It is necessary to implement the following functionality:

There is a rectangle "field", its size is 150x100 pixels. Field is split to locations, each location is 10x10 (totally 15x10 locations on the field).

There are few "coins" (5, for example), each of them can be dropped into any location.

The list of text messages should be displayed in the drop-down list if any coin is clicked (when any message is clicked, drop-down list should be hidden and coin should display the number of selected message from 0 to 9, for example).

That should be done with Silverlight 4.0

I am going to implement custom control "Coin", it will have a view (with a circle), it will display some kind of popup-window (please advise, which one), focus will be set to this window. On "FocusLost" window will be closed (without changing message number), if any message from the list will be clicked then its number will be stored inside of coin.

Question 1: is there any control that already has required functionality?

Question 2: how to implement "drag-and-drop" of coins to the "field" (lets assume, they will be close to the field)?

Any thought or ideas will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a question... it sounds like you're looking for the community to do your job defining & designing new controls for you. Consider phrasing so someone will answer, or doing research.

Comment: Sorry, don't think it looks like I am finding somebody to do my job... :) I will do, but probably something similar is implemented already... I've tried to use AutoComplete control - but can't find it in Silverlight... probably I've missed something...

Answer (score 1):

You should not place multiple questions in one 'question'.

AutoCompleteBox is in the Silverlight SDK, in the System.Windows.Controls.Input.dll assembly, and may be of help for the auto completion.